# Xcode 11: Add documentation doesn't include returns

Tags: xcode

Xcode doesn't generate the `returns` documentation whenever documentation is generated through a keyboard shortcut or from the Xcode editor.

An example of the generated documentation:

```
/// <#Description#>
/// - Parameter message: <#message description#>
func greeting(message: String) -> String {
    return message
}
```

Should be:

```
/// <#Description#>
/// - Parameter message: <#message description#>
/// - Returns: <#.....#>
func greeting(message: String) -> String {
    return message
}
```

Is this a bug or should I change a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug. Xcode's "Add Documentation" completely ignore `throws` too.

For example, for a function that `receives parameters`, `throws` and `returns`, this is what I get:

Shortcut: `⌘ + ⌥ + /`

```
/// <#Description#>
/// - Parameters:
///   - size: <#size description#>
///   - settings: <#settings description#>
func context(for size: CGSize, settings: SImageSettings = SImageSettings()) throws -> CGContext {
    // Function body.
}
```

Expected:

```
/// <#Description#>
/// - Parameters:
///   - size: <#size description#>
///   - settings: <#settings description#>
/// - Throws: 
/// - Returns: 
func context(for size: CGSize, settings: SImageSettings = SImageSettings()) throws -> CGContext {
    // Function body.
}
```

I opened [a radar](https://openradar.appspot.com/radar?id=4950005328642048).
Please also open an issue to it via [Apple Feedback](https://feedbackassistant.apple.com).